# How was the completeness theorem of propositional logic proved in the first place?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

the completeness theorem of propositional logic is one of most basic theorems which undergraduates learn about logic.

as long as I understand, it is common that the theorem is proved by means of Henkin.

But Henkin's proof didn't exist before 1949.

Then how was the completeness theorem of propositional logic proved in the first place?

I tried to find such a non-Henkin proof, but I couldn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933939/what-does-completeness-mean-in-propositional-logic)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!   But the proof showed in the previous question used maximally consistent set?  Then, is it a Henkin's proof...?

Comment: Closely related: [Earliest proof of completeness for axiomatization of Boolean algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238847/earliest-proof-of-completeness-for-axiomatization-of-boolean-algebra), where the Answer given by Andreas Blass points back to Emil Post.

Comment: See [Emil Leon Post (1897 – 1954)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Leon_Post) : "In his doctoral thesis, later shortened and published as "Introduction to a General Theory of Elementary Propositions" (1921), Post proved, among other things, that the propositional calculus of *Principia Mathematica* was complete: all tautologies are theorems, given the Principia axioms and the rules of substitution and modus ponens."

Comment: [Leon Henkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_Henkin) "was principally known for "Henkin construction", his version of the proof of the semantic completeness of standard systems of first-order logic (1949). Henkin's result was not novel; it had first been proved by Kurt Gödel in his doctoral dissertation, which was completed in 1929. (Gödel published a version of the proof in 1930.) Henkin's 1949 proof is much easier to survey than Gödel's and has thus become the standard choice of completeness proof for presentation in introductory classes and texts."

Comment: See [Soundness and completeness of propositional logic](http://resist.isti.cnr.it/free_slides/mathematical/andersen/slides2.pdf).

Comment: @hardmath Oh, thank you very much!  Because of your help, I could find the paper "Introduction to a General Theory of Elementary Propositions" by E.Post 
to which Andreas Blass referred. Probably this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Mauro Thank you for your comment! I could find the paper "Introduction to a General Theory of Elementary Propositions" on web.